# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when writing to console from windows service

Tags: c#

I have an application that is launched as Windows service.

One of the method in it is like this:

```
public void Process(ICmKofaxBatch batch)
{
    if (batch == null)
    {
        Console.Write(".");
        return;
    }
    // logic of method
}
```

Everything is fine while I don't reach check for null and write dot to console. When batch is null, I get an exception

```
    System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Count cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: count
    at System.String.CopyTo(Int32 sourceIndex, Char[] destination, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 count)
    at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(String value)
    at System.IO.TextWriter.SyncTextWriter.Write(String value)
    at System.Console.Write(String value)
    at MyCompany.CustomerCompany.Eds.Splitter.Services.Implementations.Application.ApplicationService.Process(ICmKofaxBatch batch) in d:\MyCompany\AI\src\Kofax\Custom Modules\MyCompany.CustomerCompany.Eds.Splitter\ApplicationService.cs:line 56
    at MyCompany.CustomerCompany.Eds.Splitter.SplitterCustomModule.Process(ICmKofaxBatch batch) in d:\MyCompany\AI\src\Kofax\Custom Modules\MyCompany.CustomerCompany.Eds.Splitter\SplitterCustomModule.cs:line 54
```

In which circumstances this exception can happen? I thought that when trying to output something to console from windows service, it just do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In a Windows Service, there is no ability to write to the console. I sugges you write to the Event Log or a log file.

Comment: I know that there's no ability to write to the console. But calls to Console.Write mustn't fall with exception. Console.Write writes to stdout and in case of service application it's just not defined, so Console.Write writes nowhere.

Comment: Wait, you're arguing that hitting yourself in the head with a hammer shouldn't hurt?